# command-line method to add crop marks to an A3 PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-generation, pdftk

I have A3 PDFs which are 2x2 imposed A5 postcards.

I want to add crop marks to the A3 PDFs.

I used Multivalent to create the A3 PDFs, but it doesn't appear to provide an option to add crop marks.

Does anyone have any idea how I should approach this?

I've seen hints that PDFTK can do this, but have not found any details on their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can produce an A3 PDF of some crop marks, using a graphics program, you can then overlay it using [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/):

cpdf -stamp-on cropmarks.pdf input.pdf -o output.pdf

Comment: can this add the overlay as a "background" such that the crop marks are in the margin?I mean, the goal is to produce an A3 PDF that can be printed on paper which is slightly larger than A3 (I don't know the term - I'm just the programmer), with the crop-marks appearing in the paper's margins but not in the A3 print area.

Comment: thanks - this nearly appears to be what I need. I'm very close to finishing it now